# Access Adapter items of Recyclerview

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I'm using Recyclerview to show a list. I want to delete some items like IOS. In my listview template I have added a button to delete item which is invisible by default. In my activity I have another button attached at bottom (Not part of listview) and on tap of this button I want to make all delete buttons of listview visible.

My Question is how can I get reference to all delete buttons of listview in activity and is it the right way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have [ViewHolders](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) set up, you already have references to all the buttons in your list. All you have to do is to make them visible for every item in the list with a simple loop.

In case you haven't implemented [ViewHolders](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) I suggest you check out the documentation and take a look at some simple tutorials on how to use them.

On a side note. If I understood correctly you're making a bottom tab for your app and since you referenced iOS I gotta say this; Remember that Android and iOS are two unique operating systems with their own ways of handling things. Check out Googles [pure Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html).

Answer (score 1):

In your question title you say RecyclerView, but in your text you say ListView.  The solution is similar either way, but it's best to be perfectly clear what you're doing.

In either case, there are at least two different solutions.

First, you could use a boolean flag to determine if all the the item buttons should be showing or not.  You check this flag at the time the item view is inflated or created and toggle the button accordingly.  If the boolean flag is ever changed, the easiest thing to do is tell the RecyclerView/ListView that the underlying data has changed and to redraw all the views.  Call notifyDatasetChanged on the adapter.

The other thing you can do at the time the item buttons should change is iterate all the visible item views, find the button, and change its visibility.  With RecyclerView, you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview), and with ListView you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114380/in-an-android-listview-how-can-i-iterate-manipulte-all-the-child-views-not-jus).