# App crashes when i get all value from all edittext from listview

Tags: android, listview

Hello I have implemented listview where i used one edittext in listview,and i am getting all the values from all edittext but i am getting following error and aoo crashes

my code to get values is like below.

```
 for (int k = 0; k < imagelist.getCount(); k++) {
                        EditText et;
                        Log.v("aaaaaa"," sss "+k);
                        vv = imagelist.getChildAt(k);

                             et = (EditText) vv.findViewById(R.id.pimgqty);//getting error at this line


                    }
```

Comment: What is _imagelist_ here ? If its listview then use `getChildCount()` instead of `getCount()`

Comment: Listview.......

Comment: it works till two position

Comment: after that it crashes

Comment: What crashes? What is says?

Comment: till third position there is no problem but at from forth position it gives error

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114380/in-an-android-listview-how-can-i-iterate-manipulte-all-the-child-views-not-jus

Comment: ya i checked the link

Comment: but i want value from all edittext without scrolling

Comment: Can you update the code where you are initializing the list?

Answer (score 0):

Just Create one model class and in that create one varible to save ediitext Value.and then traverse that list you will get all ediitext values